# How to compress a folder into a zip/rar file while ignoring files listed in the .gitignore file

Tags: zip, rar

I'm looking for a way to compress a folder into a zip or rar file while automatically excluding files listed in each .gitignore file per each repo in this folder\subfolder.
The challenge is that each folder may not be a Git repository, but it contains subfolders that might be (so `git ...` based commands would probably fail).

[gitzip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitzip) npm package seem to work but very slow, old and unstable.

Is there a straightforward solution for this task? Surprisingly, I've searched extensively and did not find a straightforward solution.

Both graphical and CLI solutions are fine, any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Seeing as how this is a computer programming site, it would be straightforward to write Python code to do that, including proper handling of the .gitignore syntax. This is not, however, a site to find utilities. You might try https://superuser.com instead for that.

Comment: A cli commands can be interpreted as code, doesn't it? Bash/powershell are preferred in this scenario as an answer but python is also valid

Comment: Yes, a shell script that _you_ would write would count as a programming here. I interpreted "CLI" as an already-existing command-line utility, however it was implemented. In the case of shell script, Python, C++, etc. code you would write, you would be asked here to first put in your question your attempted code that didn't quite work.